# How to specify the URL to proxy in Apache2 httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have a Spring application deployed in Tomcat that I want to proxy its URLs through an Apache2 web server, for now I do it like follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ProxyPass /app/login http://localhost/app/login
  ProxyPassReverse /app/login http://localhost/app/login
  ProxyPass /app/home http://localhost/app/home
  ProxyPass /app/profile http://localhost/app/profile
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

First is it OK to do that ? Is it possible to do through only `/login` and then specify `DocumentRoot`?

Thanks

Comment: The relative position of the `DocumentRoot` directive  within a VirtualHost block is unimportant. - You can simplify your configuration by using only  `ProxyPass /app http://localhost/app` 
 and  `ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost/app`  rather than separately  ProxyPass every subdirectory your app is using but that is the lazy sysadmin in me. - And normally one runs your application server(s) and such on custom ports like 8080 and have your web server / reverse proxy on the default http (80) and/or https (443) port.